# Two different versions of SVD?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be a very general matrix (meaning, it can be fat, long, full column rank, not full column rank, etc). The SVD I used to know is

$$X_{n\times p} = U_{n\times p} D_{p\times p} V_{p\times p}^T $$

Today I was reading Wikipedia, which decompose $X$ as

$$X_{n\times p} = U_{n\times n} D_{n\times p} V^T_{p \times p}$$

Why do we have two different SVD's? Are they equivalent to each other?

Comment: The first one is what's called a "thin SVD", and the second one is a "full SVD". The thin one can be derived from the full one by deleting the last few rows of $\mathbf D$ so that it is square, and then taking the first $p$ left singular vectors to form $\mathbf U$ (equivalently, first $p$ columns of $\mathbf U$). A similar situation exists in QR decomposition.

Comment: "Thin" versions are often the most computationally useful ones, since they take up less storage.